# Можно ли поменять программно иконку в MenuItem?

Tags: java, android, меню

Файл menu_main.xml находится item с id menu_share

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Favorite" />
```

Я попробовал в Активити в onCreate написать код, который бы взависимости от условия менял бы иконку

```
        MenuItem itt = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.menu_share);
    switch (сontact.favorite) {
        case "0":
            itt.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp);
            break;

        case "1":
            itt.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp);
            break;
    }
```

Но вылетает ошибка на строке itt.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_white_24dp); или на второй строке взависимости от условия.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Меню ещё не существует в onCreate методе. Оно создаётся только в onCreateOptionsMenu, а манипулировать им надо в `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. И искать меню надо не так, а вот так:

```
/** Called whenever we call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem  itt = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);

    //здесь по условию меняйте меню

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Теперь для перерисовки меню вызывайте `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` - вызовется этот метод и перерисует вам меню.

---

Если тулбар не является `ActionBar`-ом, то получайте ссылки на элементы меню так:

```
MenuItem  itt = toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_share);
```

Comment: Да код отлично срабатывает, если использовать setSupportActionBar(toolbar); но я не могу к сожалению его использовать, своя особенность в приложении.
Можно ли  как-то обойти это??

Comment: @Artsait, используйте второй вариант из моего ответа

Comment: Спасибо!!! Все работает